# dplyr compatibility issue with custom S3 classes

Tags: r, dplyr

I wrote a small R package, called [**`errors`**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=errors), that associates errors to numeric vectors and enables transparent error propagation. I am struggling to make it fully compatible with `dplyr`.

First, let's take the well-known `iris` dataset and assign a 5% of error to every numerical variable:

```
library(errors)
library(dplyr)

iris_errors <- iris %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-Species), funs(set_errors(., .*0.05)))

head(iris_errors)                         # ok
```

Every column is an `errors` S3 object, with 150 values and their associated 150 errors:

```
length(iris_errors$Sepal.Length)          # 150
length(errors(iris_errors$Sepal.Length))  # 150
```

Now, let's say we want the average for each column by species:

```
iris_mean <- iris_errors %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise_all(mean)

head(iris_mean)                           # error
```

Apparently, it works, but the formatter fails when we try to print it. What happened is that, at some point, we lost all the errors but the first one:

```
length(iris_mean$Sepal.Length)            # 3
length(errors(iris_mean$Sepal.Length))    # 1!
```

Comment: Did you define a subsetting operator for your class? It would be nicer if you provided a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in the question itself that didn't rely on installing the package to debug,

Comment: Yes, I defined the subsetting operators. The same example, without the package, would require many functions defined in the package, so I don't see the point of it. Moreover, it's on CRAN and it has no dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that working with attributes in `dplyr` is not a trivial issue (see [tidyverse/dplyr#2773](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2773)). They have plans for this, but it won't work for the time being.

This is a pure-R version of the grouped summary I was trying to do with `dplyr`:

```
by(iris_errors, iris_errors$Species, function(i) {
  i$Species <- NULL
  lapply(i, mean)
})
```